# Blocks from gradio package unable to receive a custmized function that reads the csv or excel file

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, gradio

I want to manually select and upload a CSV or Excel file through `gradio` (tutorial of gradio), and display it on the UI interface. First, I wrote a function `read_file()` to read Excel or CSV files:

```py
import gradio as gr
import csv
import pandas as pd

def read_file(file_path):
    if file_path.endswith('.csv'):
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    elif file_path.endswith('.xlsx') or file_path.endswith('.xls'):
        data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    else:
        raise ValueError('File type not supported. Please provide a CSV or Excel file.')
    return data

df = read_file('./test_data.csv')
print(df)
```

Out:

```
        date        M0
0    2009-07  34239.30
1    2009-08  34406.62
2    2009-09  36787.89
3    2009-10  35730.23
4    2009-11  36343.86
..       ...       ...
```

As you can see, this function can read the test CSV file correctly, but when I pass it to `gr.Blocks`, an error will appear:

```py
with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    a = gr.File()
    a.change(fn=read_file, inputs=[a], outputs=[])

demo.launch(debug=True)
```

The error message indicates that `_io.BufferedRandom` object has no attribute `endswith`:

```
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedRandom' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If we use `gr.Interface` instead of insisting on `gr.Blocks`, the following code will work:

```
import gradio as gr
import csv
import pandas as pd

def read_excel_file(file_path):
    if file_path.name.endswith('.csv'):
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path.name)
    elif file_path.name.endswith('.xlsx') or file_path.name.endswith('.xls'):
        data = pd.read_excel(file_path.name)
    else:
        raise ValueError('File type not supported. Please provide a CSV or Excel file.')
    return data

file_input = gr.inputs.File(label="Upload Excel File")
output = gr.outputs.Dataframe(type='pandas')

interface = gr.Interface(fn=read_excel_file, inputs=file_input, outputs=output)
interface.launch()
```